# Complex numbers homework.

Tags: complex-numbers

I've got a quick question.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/92XiL.jpg (sorry I couldn't make an image here)

And I am confused. Because "y" is an imaginary number and I couldn't calculate x which is I guess 0 ? And even if my "y" is imaginary I still have real numbers such as 1/2. Because my "y" is equal 1/2 - 1/2*i.

But if I get Re{z} out of this :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QZIG.jpg

Then I get a contradiction.

I don't get it.

Comment: Not sure what the question is.  Is it "find all $z\in \mathbb C$ such that $\overline {z-i}=z-1$"?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: @lulu I'm not sure I got it from the friend of mine and tried to calculate just trying find "z". But then I was stuck with the thing that "y" had real number

Comment: Well, we can't help you guess what question you meant to ask.  If it is the question I wrote, then there are no such $z$.

Comment: Both of your solutions have a mistake in one step.

Comment: I suspect that you have misrepresented the original problem, and I advise you to double check the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it in two ways too.

First way: Let $z=x+iy$. Then,

$\begin{align}
\overline{z-i}=z-1\implies 
&\overline{x+iy-i}=x+iy-1\\\implies 
&\overline{x+(y-1)i}=x-1+iy\\\implies
&x-(y-1)i=x-1+iy\\\implies
&x=x-1\\\implies
&0=-1
\end{align}$

which is acontradiction. So, there is no solution of the equation $\overline{z-i}=z-1$.

Second way: Let again $z=x+iy$.

$\begin{align}
\overline{z-i}=z-1\implies 
&\overline{z+(-i)}=z-1\\\implies 
&\overline{z}+\overline{-i}=z-1\\\implies
&\overline{z}+i=z-1\\\implies
&\overline{z}-z=-1-i\\\implies
&-2yi=-1-i\\\implies
&\Re{(-2yi)}=\Re{(-1-i)}\\\implies
&0=-1
\end{align}$

which is again a contradiction. In one step I used $\overline{z}-z=-2\Im{(z)}i=-2yi$.

Comment: Yey so I was right that I made a mistake somewhere :D Okey but my suspection that there is no solution for "z".